# Multihop with sshpass

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, ssh-config

I want to use `.ssh/config` to connect to a host through a gateway. I don't want to set up an RSA key and have to use password. I have previously done this kind of hopping without password. Now trying to do it with password.

A direct command that works for me is:

`sshpass -p mypassword ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh gateway -W %h:%p" myusername@myip`

Where I have already set up key auth in gateway and it's details are present in my .ssh/config. To set this up in `.ssh/config`, I tried the following:

```
Host h_act
      <username, hostname, port etc.>
      ProxyCommand ssh gateway -W %h:%p
Host h
      ProxyCommand sshpass -p mypassword ssh h_act
```

However, when I try `ssh h`, I get `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated as stdin is not a terminal`. I tried `-vtt` with ssh to get weird messages, but no terminal. I know that a chain of ProxyCommand works when there is a `netcat/nc` or just `ssh -W` with it. But here, it is not working. Even when I try the last command without sshpass, I get the same error. I am guessing it has to do with certain expectations that ProxyCommand has with the command that follows and I am not able to fulfill them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your configuration is the same as that one-liner, it looks more like this:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='sshpass -p mypassword ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh gateway -W %h:%p" h_act' myusername@myip
```

i.e. you have the `sshpass` running inside a ProxyCommand.

But I don't think that will work, `sshpass` wraps the `ssh` client in a pseudo-terminal, hiding the fact that the password actually comes from a file or something other than user input from a terminal. To do this, it needs to run before the `ssh` client runs.

If your first one-liner works, but you just don't feel like typing the `sshpass` each time, you can wrap it in a shell script:

```
#/bin/sh
sshpass -f passwordfile ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh gateway -W %h:%p" "$@"
```

Then run with something like `sshscript myusername@myip`.

As an aside, don't use `sshpass -p`, it will make the password visible in `ps` output for as long as the `ssh` client (and `sshpass`) runs. Better use `sshpass -e` to pass the pw through the environment, or `sshpass -f file` to read it from a file.

Comment: Thanks. The explanation about why the sshpass wouldn't work inside ProxyCommand was useful. I have to go with the alternate approach then. I was trying to get it done using `.ssh/config`.